# How to restore a Mac if you forgot recovery password

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, firmware-password

As the title, is there a way to restore a Mac when you forgot the recovery password, I tried with command + R during reboot, but it doesn’t help.

Comment: When you say recovery Password are you saying there is a firmware lock in place?

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents firmware passwords and how you want to schedule an in person appointment if [you lose the password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293631/macbook-pro-locked-disabled/293706):

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

> ### If you forgot your firmware password
>
> If you can't remember your firmware password or passcode, schedule an in-person service appointment with an Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider. Bring your Mac to the appointment, and bring your original receipt or invoice as proof of purchase.