# No longer admin on Mac

Tags: macos, password, administrator

So I have a 2011 MacBook Pro that I received from a friend of mine. It had Sierra on the Mac and I was able to upgrade it to High Sierra. The account that I used to do all this was an admin account that I was able create when my friend gave it to me. I am planning on going to school for Software Development so I started setting up my Windows and Mac to do this on either or.

I googled how to set up your Mac for software development and found this website: https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/mac-setup/

I’ve got about half way through this process when my life took somewhat of a turn and had to focus on other things. Fast forward a few months of not using my Mac I go on it to continue the process and I notice I don’t have admin rights anymore. There’s another account that has admin rights and now my account is a managed account. Both Firmware and FileVault are on and I can’t turn them off without an admin password, which I don’t have to this account. I’m stuck and unsure how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've linked to some similar questions with answers on the top of your post. If you forgot the firmware password you set months ago https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364471/how-to-restore-a-mac-if-you-forgot-recovery-password seems to be the way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks! I remember the firmware password but it’s that new account that’s throwing me off. I’ll look into answers you sent me!

Comment: If you are still stuck afterwards, please edit your question to focus on the place/step you are stuck with, and describe what you (unsuccessfully) did to solve it.

Comment: Okay so I can’t seem to do the answers/fixes to this issue mainly because firmware is active and I can’t disable it. Can’t boot into single user mode and using terminal in recovery mode doesn’t seem to do the trick either. I also know the firmware password

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect that, it will then be automatically placed in the review queue to have the hold removed.