# Changed my User Name and Now I cannot unlock any authentications

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator

Yes, that's right, I did what I wasn't supposed to do and now I'm paying the price.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I went into my Users & Groups, unlocked it, went into advanced options and changed the user name because someone had misspelled it when they entered it.

The main issue now is that when I try and click the lock the prompt comes up asking for a user name and password. The user name portion of the prompt USED TO be filled in.  It is now blank.  I know that password because (A) that's how I get into the main log-in screen and (B) I didn't change that.

I have tried all sorts of user names but none of them seem to work to unlock anything.  My questions are:

1) How can I recover my user name (it does show up in current user) but that user name doesn't work and hasn't changed.

2) Once Im able to unlock that again, can I just switch back to the previous user name?

3) And if I can do that, is there a way to determine what the original user name was?

I have read a few of the other threads which were similar to my situation and have executed a few of the Terminal procedures but haven't had any success.

This computer is running High Sierra 10.13.6
My current admin user type is Standard (not Admin)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password is the canonical for questions like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372888/no-longer-admin-on-mac and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/57119?lq=1 When I went through that, I had a fresh laptop, so I did  a fresh re-install.

Comment: Did you follow these steps when you changed your username? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548 If not they might show you what you missed

Comment: Re your q3, how do you not know what the original was? You say you changed it because of a mis-spelling...