# How can I undo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused if I don't know firmware password?

Tags: startup, recovery, firmware, nvram, firmware-password

While trying to get into recovery mode, I used this:

`sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused`

... hoping it'd take me directly to recovery mode. Instead, it prompts me for the firmware password. Which I don't know. And I can't clear NVRAM without the firmware password. So, I'm stuck in a reboot loop.

Yes, I'm an idiot. How do I get myself out of this mess?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to enter the firmware password.  If you don’t remember it, you can take to Apple along with proof of purchase, and they can unlock for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This depends on your hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63135/how-can-i-reset-the-firmware-password-on-a-macbook-air). Best bet is web chat with Apple to rule out any self rescue options as they will know exactly what to do for any sort of hardware. Also, they will be needed if you have to [provide proof of purchase to get vendor unlock code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293631/macbook-pro-locked-disabled).

- https://locate.apple.com